# 3D Max - Plane question

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, maxscript

I've only a basic knowledge of 3D Max. I'm creating a plane using MaxScript, converting it to an editable Poly and then extruding certain faces. The thing is, I only have 16 faces to work from. Is there a way to have more than 16 faces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to define it before you do your conversion to poly.

The syntax shown in the listener for adding segments is:

```
$.lengthsegs = 20
$.widthsegs = 20
```

So for your script just add this right below your line where you define your plane:

```
yPlane.lengthsegs =20 --any number of segments 
yPlane.widthsegs = 20 --any number of segments
```

this makes it more "bulletproof",
since when using $ it means any selected object.

By using "yplane" variable we make sure it only affects this object.

Comment: just add this right below your line where you define your plane:
yPlane.lengthsegs =20 --any number of segments
yPlane.widthsegs = 20 --any number of segments

this makes it more "bulletproof" since when using $ it means any selected object, by using "yplane" we make sure it only affects this object.

Answer (score 1):

And in case you have similar questions in the future, just turn on the MAXScript macro recorder and perform the edit in the 3ds Max UI. Most of the times, the recorder will show you the MAXScript code for your action.